# Date sorting in Datatables not sorting as expected

Tags: javascript, datatables, datatables-1.10

When I sort a table by the date field using the uk-date plugin the dates seem to be messed up by nulls. These nulls seem to stay in the middle of the order. Then after it then restarts the dates. The data is populated from an array. When i try modifying the code it seems to either break the date formatting or make it so nulls are always at the start. Rather than start or end based on if you sort asc/desc. It is also using date time moment plugin.

```
    <script>var resp_53 = true; var datatablearraycols_53_a = [{"orderable": false, "bSortable": false, "className":"no-sort", "searchable": false,},null,null,null,null,null,{ type: "date-uk" },null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
    ];</script>
```

```
                    {
                        "columns": datatablearraycols_53_a,
                        "data": datatablearray_53_a,
                        "processing": true,
                        stateSave: true,
                        "responsive": resp_53,
                        "scrollX": !resp_53,
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "targets": 'no-sort',
                            "orderable": false,
                        }],
                        "dom": '<fB<t>lip>',
                        "buttons": [
                            { extend: 'csvHtml5', text: 'Export' }
                        ]
                    });
```

Comment: Can you create a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365), so we have a runnable demonstration (with data) which shows all the relevant code, with some test data, and all the DataTables & Moment resources you are using? That way, we can recreate the error. See also [mre].